# Hive: Insert from one table to another all missing records based on max date

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another on a daily basis.

Table A has data added to it from a 3rd party and I then need to take any new data they added into my table stored somewhere else:

So: Insert all records from table A that are not in table B everyday based on the date column.

This is what I tried however it takes almost forever to run and doesn't seem very clean.

```
INSERT INTO table B
PARTITION (`date_col`)
SELECT col_1, date_col
FROM A
WHERE cast(`date_col` as date) NOT IN (select `date_col` from B);
```

Is there a clean and efficent way for me to do this? I wish I could store the max date of table B in a variable and then do something like:

```
WHERE cast(`date_col` as date) > max_date_of_table_B;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try on this.

```
set max_date='2018-12-31'; --whatever date you wanted to keep

INSERT INTO table B
PARTITION (`date_col`)
SELECT col_1, date_col
FROM A
WHERE cast(`date_col` as date) > ${hiveconf:max_date};
```

Comment: max_date is not a static value, it should be dynamic based on the max_date from Table B.

So I would need something like:

`set max_date= select max(date_col) from table B;` 

but I don't think I can do that.

Comment: If dynamic, then We might need to go for a shell/python script.